# WebM Video won't play in Firefox 4

Tags: html5-video, firefox4, webm

I cannot get this video to play in Firefox 4.

http://m1.animedlc.com/webm_test/

It plays fine in Chrome. I haven't tried anything else besides FF4 and Chrome. I converted it from a avi file. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little more research told me to add `AddType video/webm .webm` to my .htaccess and that worked fine.